# Folder IDs for Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, folder

Is there any way to get the folder IDs in Content Builder like we see in data extensions? As you know, when you hover the folder with your mouse in data extension part, you can see the IDs of the folders.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy way to get the ID from the content builder folder display.

If you need this as a one-off, there is a workaround:

- In the folder tree to the left, right click on the right of the folder you want to ID (if you right click on the folder directly, you get a CB-specific interaction, you want to click on the right of it to get default browser behavior)
- Then select "inspect" or "inspect element". You will see the HTML for it in the browser dev tools: [image: category markup to see id]
- Look for the data-id attribute. Like in here 257730.

Answer (score 0):

On the email studio -> content builder:

1. Go to the parent folder
2. Click on "show folders" (top center/left)
3. Click on the gear icon (top right, under "create")
4. Select "ID"